# How to extract data from json file

Tags: c#, json, list

I have a json file in this format

```
{
 "myserver": {
  "readonly": false,
  "slaveonly": false
  },
 "dateChanged": true,
 "pid": "3875",

"data-mode": {
"version": 461329,
"mode": "delta",
"Jobs" : { 
           "job-mode": "full",
            "1" : { id : 100, description : "descritpion 1" },
            "2" : { id : 200, description : "descritpion 1" },
            "3" : { id : 300, description : "descritpion 1" }
          }
 }
 }
```

I have a class named Job

```
public class Job
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}

}
```

I need list of all the jobs as IList 
from the json string.

I need to read all the values in Jobs tag (1,2,3). I have done some work here.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"10022017.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic obj  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            //obj.
            // var xx = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)obj).ChildrenTokens).Items[14])).Value).ChildrenTokens).Items[6])).Value).ChildrenTokens;

            var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
            var data = jObj.Descendants()
                .OfType<JProperty>()
                .Where(p => p.Name == "jobs");

            foreach (var item in data.Descendants())
            {

            }

        }
```

Dont know how to get value for each row and convert into some class.

Help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Create a class that represents the whole of your input JSON and then use the `DeserializeObject<T>` method instead. (You can paste JSON as a class in Visual Studio).

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact `json string` because I think this is not correct. Can you verify it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes your mistake is "jobs"| "Jobs"..

you can use As an alternaive..

```
        var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText); ;
        var jobs = jObj["data-mode"]["Jobs"];
        var result = jobs.OfType<JProperty>().Where((a,b)=>{
            int key = 0;
            return int.TryParse(a.Name,out key);
        }).Select<JProperty,Job>((jp,i) => {
            return new Job
            {
                Id = jp.Value["id"].ToObject<string>(),
                Desc = jp.Value["description"].ToObject<string>()
            };
        }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I owe you two beers. it works as charm my friend. thanks a lot.